# Handle PHP multidimensional array to assign key as parent of value array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Initial array i've started with:**

```
{
    "0":{
        "id":"1",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
        "title":"Mag.",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "4":{
        "id":"11",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
        "title":"Mag. BG",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"},
    "1":{
        "id":"2",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
        "title":"Mag.",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "5":{
        "id":"12",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
        "title":"Mag. BG",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"},
    "2":{
        "id":"3",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner",
        "title":"Mag",
        "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "3":{
        "id":"4",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"Ziegler Verena",
        "title":"MA",
        "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "6":{
        "id":"13",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner BG",
        "title":"Mag BG",
        "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"},
    "7":{
        "id":"14",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"Ziegler Verena BG",
        "title":"MA BG",
        "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"
    }
}
```

**I've got an array that looks like:**

```
{
    "Business development":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "country_id":"Austria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
            "title":"Mag.",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
            "phone":"0"
        },{
            "id":"11",
            "country_id":"Bulgaria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
            "title":"Mag. BG",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
            "phone":"0"
        }
    ],
    "Technical contact":[
        {
            "id":"2",
            "country_id":"Austria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
            "title":"Mag.",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
            "phone":"0"
        },{
            "id":"12",
            "country_id":"Bulgaria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
            "title":"Mag. BG",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
            "phone":"0"
        }
    ],
    "VAT leader":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "country_id":"Austria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
            "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner",
            "title":"Mag",
            "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at",
            "phone":"0"
        },{
            "id":"4",
            "country_id":"Austria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
            "name":"Ziegler Verena",
            "title":"MA",
            "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
            "phone":"0"
        },{
            "id":"13",
            "country_id":"Bulgaria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
            "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner BG",
            "title":"Mag BG",
            "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at BG",
            "phone":"0"
        },{
            "id":"14",
            "country_id":"Bulgaria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
            "name":"Ziegler Verena BG",
            "title":"MA BG",
            "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at BG",
            "phone":"0"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And i want it to look like:**

```
{
    "Business development":[
        "Austria": [
            "id":"1",
            "country_id":"Austria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
            "title":"Mag.",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
            "phone":"0"
        ], 
        "Bulgaria": [
            "id":"11",
            "country_id":"Bulgaria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
            "title":"Mag. BG",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
            "phone":"0"
        ]
    ],
    "Technical contact":[
        "Austria": [
            "id":"2",
            "country_id":"Austria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
            "title":"Mag.",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
            "phone":"0"
        ], 
        "Bulgaria": [
            "id":"12",
            "country_id":"Bulgaria",
            "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
            "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
            "title":"Mag. BG",
            "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
            "phone":"0"
        ]
    ],
    "VAT leader":[
        "Austria": [
            {
                "id":"3",
                "country_id":"Austria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner",
                "title":"Mag",
                "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at",
                "phone":"0"
            },{
                "id":"4",
                "country_id":"Austria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"Ziegler Verena",
                "title":"MA",
                "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
                "phone":"0"
            }
        ], 
        "Bulgaria": [
            {
                "id":"13",
                "country_id":"Bulgaria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner BG",
                "title":"Mag BG",
                "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at BG",
                "phone":"0"
            },{
                "id":"14",
                "country_id":"Bulgaria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"Ziegler Verena BG",
                "title":"MA BG",
                "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at BG",
                "phone":"0"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**What i did so far:**

```
function prepare_data($array, $primary_instance, $dependency=NULL){
    $handled_data = [];
    $cloned = $array;

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($cloned as $key => $value) {
            if ($k != $key && $v[$primary_instance] == $value[$primary_instance]) {
                if (!in_array($value[$primary_instance], $handled_data) ) {
                    $handled_data[$value[$primary_instance]][] = $v;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // if has dependencies, handle it
    if(!is_null($dependency)){
        $cloned = $handled_data;

        foreach ($handled_data as $k => $v) {
            foreach ($cloned as $key => $value) {
                if ($v != $value && $k[$dependency] == $key[$dependency]) {
                    if (!in_array($key[$dependency], $handled_data) ) {
                        $handled_data[$dependency][][$key[$dependency]][] = $v;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $handled_data;
}
```

**How i imagined it would work:** Call the function with initial array and add the keys `prepare_data($sorted_contacts, 'VAT_contact_person', 'country_id')`

I've managed to make it from worst to the first example using the first part of the function without `if(!is_null($dependency))` condition but now, i want to use the $dependency i'm passing in the function to structure from first example to the second example.

**EDIT:**
The final form of returned array should contain only array

**EDIT 2:**

```
"VAT leader":{
        "Austria":[
            {
                "id":"3",
                "country_id":"Austria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"Ziegler Verena",
                "title":"MA",
                "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
                "phone":"0"
            },
            {
                "id":"4",
                "country_id":"Austria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"Ziegler Verena",
                "title":"MA",
                "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
                "phone":"0"
            }
        ],
        "Bulgaria":[
            {
                "id":"13",
                "country_id":"Bulgaria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"Ziegler Verena",
                "title":"MA",
                "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
                "phone":"0"
            },
            {
                "id":"14",
                "country_id":"Bulgaria",
                "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
                "name":"Ziegler Verena",
                "title":"MA",
                "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
                "phone":"0"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: in the "what you want" half of the object are object, and the other half are arrays... can you please define when make them array or object?

Comment: If it can be turned from "initial array" (first array) to "partially handled" (second array) as array only the "final form" (final array) should be only arrays inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if we start with this array...

```
$data = json_decode('
{
    "0":{
        "id":"1",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
        "title":"Mag.",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "4":{
        "id":"11",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Business development",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
        "title":"Mag. BG",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"},
    "1":{
        "id":"2",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert",
        "title":"Mag.",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "5":{
        "id":"12",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"Technical contact",
        "name":"Mayrhofer Herbert BG",
        "title":"Mag. BG",
        "email":"herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"},
    "2":{
        "id":"3",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner",
        "title":"Mag",
        "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "3":{
        "id":"4",
        "country_id":"Austria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"Ziegler Verena",
        "title":"MA",
        "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at",
        "phone":"0"},
    "6":{
        "id":"13",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"G\u00fcnther Mayrleitner BG",
        "title":"Mag BG",
        "email":"guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"},
    "7":{
        "id":"14",
        "country_id":"Bulgaria",
        "VAT_contact_person":"VAT leader",
        "name":"Ziegler Verena BG",
        "title":"MA BG",
        "email":"verena.ziegler@mazars.at BG",
        "phone":"0"
    }
}
', true);
```

We can then build a new multidimensional array with two taxonomies: namely **VAT_contact_person** and **country_id**, by simply inserting each element in the list with those values as keys in the new array.

Like this...

```
foreach ($data as $v) {
    $finalData[$v["VAT_contact_person"]][$v["country_id"]][] = $v;
}

var_dump($finalData);
```

So the result:

```
array(3) {
  ["Business development"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Austria"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(7) "Austria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(20) "Business development"
        ["name"]=>
        string(17) "Mayrhofer Herbert"
        ["title"]=>
        string(4) "Mag."
        ["email"]=>
        string(27) "herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
    ["Bulgaria"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(8) "Bulgaria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(20) "Business development"
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "Mayrhofer Herbert BG"
        ["title"]=>
        string(7) "Mag. BG"
        ["email"]=>
        string(30) "herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
  }
  ["Technical contact"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Austria"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(7) "Austria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(17) "Technical contact"
        ["name"]=>
        string(17) "Mayrhofer Herbert"
        ["title"]=>
        string(4) "Mag."
        ["email"]=>
        string(27) "herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
    ["Bulgaria"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "12"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(8) "Bulgaria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(17) "Technical contact"
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "Mayrhofer Herbert BG"
        ["title"]=>
        string(7) "Mag. BG"
        ["email"]=>
        string(30) "herbert.mayrhofer@mazars.at BG"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
  }
  ["VAT leader"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Austria"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(7) "Austria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(10) "VAT leader"
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "Günther Mayrleitner"
        ["title"]=>
        string(3) "Mag"
        ["email"]=>
        string(30) "guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(7) "Austria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(10) "VAT leader"
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Ziegler Verena"
        ["title"]=>
        string(2) "MA"
        ["email"]=>
        string(24) "verena.ziegler@mazars.at"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
    ["Bulgaria"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "13"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(8) "Bulgaria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(10) "VAT leader"
        ["name"]=>
        string(23) "Günther Mayrleitner BG"
        ["title"]=>
        string(6) "Mag BG"
        ["email"]=>
        string(33) "guenther.mayrleitner@mazars.at BG"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "14"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(8) "Bulgaria"
        ["VAT_contact_person"]=>
        string(10) "VAT leader"
        ["name"]=>
        string(17) "Ziegler Verena BG"
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "MA BG"
        ["email"]=>
        string(27) "verena.ziegler@mazars.at BG"
        ["phone"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, it's that simple. If you take the array you've already got and run this code on it, it would give you exactly that.

Comment: It works flawless BUT the "VAT leader" has multiple values in country. For example, Austria has 2 VAT leader objects... check the "I've got an array that looks like:" object and you'll see there is missing 1 object for each country

Comment: The objects with id: 3 and id: 13 in the VAT leader are missing

Comment: Of course, you can only have one key with the same name. That's just how arrays work in PHP.

Comment: I know that, but i was thinking to identify it has multiple values and add the in an array, check the edit 2 imma put now in the question

Comment: You can't do that. That's just not possible. You would have an array of arrays, but the key would not be the country_id.

Comment: Look, you can't have it both ways. You either have `["country"=>"value"]` or you have `["country" => ["value", "value", "value]]`.

Comment: Some countries have a single value while others can have multiple inputs for the same country. The only problem now with your code is that a value of a country is lost. i thought it will create an array for that country with both values

Comment: Imma accept your answer, i like it too much. I'm sure we'll fix it till the end (dont lose data)

Comment: @OzZie you really shouldn't accept an answer that doesn't actually work. For one thing, it will discourage other users from answering and giving you a solution that does work.

Comment: Again, that would give you a very different result from what you're expecting, because the result can no longer be a key that points to an array with the values you're expecting. Instead, what you get is an array of arrays: `["country" => [["foo"], ["bar"], ["baz"]]]` See the difference? I assume you wanted the key to be the country to make it easier to access the value. But now you've just over complicated the entire thing defeating all intended benefits. You might as well leave it as an array.

Comment: Look, I've edited the answer to more accurately reflect what you're asking. The original question simply alludes to a solution that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Sherif This is it! This is what i was looking for and i can get rid of all of my function. Thanks alot m8 and sorry for the bad explanation